# Push an object on to an array containing the same key

Tags: php, arrays

This might seem super easy but to me its not, I have the following method:

```
public function addRadioButtonTab($groupName, $radioButtonTab)
{
    $radioButtonTab           = new RadioButtonTab($radioButtonTab);
    $this->radioButtonTabs[][$groupName] = $groupName;
    $this->radioButtonTabs[][] = $radioButtonTab;
}
```

I want to push the `$radioButtonTab` into the same array that contains the key: `$groupName`.

Right now I get two separate arrays, one with the `key=>value` and one with the object.

Comment: Did you mean `$this->radioButtonTabs[$groupName][] = $radioButtonTab;`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat no that then creates the same key as `$groupName `but this time its value is the `$radioButtonTab` object. It needs to be: `[group_name => $name, $radioButtonTab]` not `[group_name => $name], [group_name => $radioButtonTab]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of looping and doing complex things try this:

```
public function addRadioButtonTab($groupName, $radioButtonTab)
{
    $radioButtonTab                      = new RadioButtonTab($radioButtonTab);
    $this->radioButtonTabs[][$groupName] = array($groupName, $radioButtonTab);
}
```

Comment: Is `$this->radioButtonTabs[][$groupName]` really valid syntax?

Comment: yes this will create an associative array and push it to a simple array in the next free cell. ex : `$t[]['Rocket'] = 'Hazmat'` **==>** 
`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Rocket"]=>
    string(6) "Hazmat"
  }
}`

Comment: Neat!  I didn't know you could do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should make an array of the values you want first, then append that to `$this->radioButtonTabs`.

```
public function addRadioButtonTab($groupName, $radioButtonTab)
{
    $radioButtonTab = new RadioButtonTab($radioButtonTab);

    // Just append arrays into the main array
    $this->radioButtonTabs[] = array('group_name' => $groupName, $radioButtonTab);

    // Or if you want your array to use `$groupName` as a key
    $this->radioButtonTabs[$groupName] = array('group_name' => $groupName, $radioButtonTab)
}
```